# Receiving "appliction not responding" error

Tags: 22.04, qt

THANKS HAL

I started receiving this error after upgrading Ubuntu:

[image: "QT Creator is not responding" error]

I receive this periodically after some functions are activated. I honestly do not recall exactly when this started, but I am currently using:

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux nov251-desktop 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This error is not limited to Qt applications, but it is almost certain to get this after I run `build` or `run`, most commonly used options/commands, in Qt.

Reversing to older Ubuntu version is NOT an option.

I would like to solve this annoying, time consuming problem, and any help to achieve that goal would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can AI actually answer my question ?